# Filter by custom QuerySet of a related model in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

Let's say I have two models: `Book` and `Author`

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    country = models.CharField()
    approved = models.BooleanField()


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    approved = models.BooleanField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
```

Each of the two models has an `approved` attribute, which shows or hides the object from the website. If the `Book` is not approved, it is hidden. If the `Author` is not approved, all his books are hidden.

In order to define these criteria in a DRY manner, making a custom QuerySet looks like a perfect solution:

```
class AuthorQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def for_site():
        return self.filter(approved=True)

class BookQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def for_site():
        reuturn self.filter(approved=True).filter(author__approved=True)
```

After hooking up these QuerysSets to the corresponding models, they can be queried like this: `Book.objects.for_site()`, without the need to hardcode all the filtering every time.

---

Nevertheless, this solution is still not perfect. Later I can decide to add another filter to authors:

```
class AuthorQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def for_site():
        return self.filter(approved=True).exclude(country='Problematic Country')
```

but this new filter will only work in `Author.objects.for_site()`, but not in `Book.objects.for_site()`, since there it is hardcoded.

---

So my questions is: **is it possible to apply a custom queryset of a related model when filtering on a different model**, so that it looks similar to this:

```
class BookQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet):
    def for_site():
        reuturn self.filter(approved=True).filter(author__for_site=True)
```

where `for_site` is a custom QuerySet of the `Author` model.

Comment: I'm not sure if that helps, but try [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/08/16/django-tip-11-custom-manager-with-chainable-querysets.html)

Comment: This is exactly what I refer to with *After hooking up these QuerysSets to the corresponding models*. But I don't see how it helps with using that manager to filter instances of another related model. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: You're not missing something, I really think it is a good question, I don't think you'll find something out of the box. You can have a look on the [docs for custom lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-lookups/) and code something for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I've come up with a solution based on `Q` objects, which are described in the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects). This is definitely not the most elegant solution one can invent, but it works. See the code below.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q


######## Custom querysets
class QuerySetRelated(models.query.QuerySet):
    """Queryset that can be applied in filters on related models"""

    @classmethod
    def _qq(cls, q, related_name):
        """Returns a Q object or a QuerySet filtered with the Q object, prepending fields with the related_name if specified"""
        if not related_name:
            # Returning Q object without changes
            return q
        # Recursively updating keywords in this and nested Q objects
        for i_child in range(len(q.children)):
            child = q.children[i_child]
            if isinstance(child, Q):
                q.children[i_child] = cls._qq(child, related_name)
            else:
                q.children[i_child] = ('__'.join([related_name, child[0]]), child[1])
        return q


class AuthorQuerySet(QuerySetRelated):

    @classmethod
    def for_site_q(cls, q_prefix=None):
        q = Q(approved=True)
        q = q & ~Q(country='Problematic Country')
        return cls._qq(q, q_prefix)


    def for_site(self):
        return self.filter(self.for_site_q())


class BookQuerySet(QuerySetRelated):

    @classmethod
    def for_site_q(cls, q_prefix=None):
        q = Q(approved=True) & AuthorQuerySet.for_site_q('author')
        return cls._qq(q, q_prefix)


    def for_site(self):
        return self.filter(self.for_site_q())



######## Models
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    approved = models.BooleanField()

    objects = AuthorQuerySet.as_manager()


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    approved = models.BooleanField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)

    objects = BookQuerySet.as_manager()
```

This way, whenever the `AuthorQuerySet.for_site_q()` method is changed, it will be automatically reflected in the `BookQuerySet.for_site()` method.

Here the custom `QuerySet` classes perform selection at the class level by combining different `Q` objects, instead of using `filter()` or `exclude()` methods at the object level. Having a `Q` object allows 3 different ways of using it:

1. put it inside a `filter()` call, to filter a queryset in place;
2. combine it with other `Q` objects using `& (AND)` or `| (OR)` operators;
3. dynamically change names of keywords used in the `Q` objects by accessing its `children` attribute, which is defined in the superclass [`django.utils.tree.Node`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/tree.py)

The `_qq()` method defined in every custom `QuerySet` class takes care of prepending the specified `related_name` to all filter keys.

If we have a `q = Q(approved=True)` object, then we can have the following outputs:

1. `self._qq(q)` – is equivalent to `self.filter(approved=True)`;
2. `self._qq(q, 'author')` – is equivalent to `self.filter(author__approved=True)`

---

This solution still has serious drawbacks:

1. one has to import and call custom `QuerySet` class of the related model explicitly;
2. for each filter method one has to define two methods `filter_q` (class method) and `filter` (instance method);

---

**UPDATE:** The drawback `2.` can be partially reduced by creating filter methods dynamically:

```
# in class QuerySetRelated
    @classmethod
    def add_filters(cls, names):
        for name in names:
            method_q = getattr(cls, '{0:s}_q'.format(name))
            def function(self, *args, **kwargs):
                return self.filter(method_q(*args, **kwargs))
            setattr(cls, name, function)

AuthorQuerySet.add_filters(['for_site'])
BookQuerySet.add_filters(['for_site'])
```

---

Therefore, if someone comes up with a more elegant solution, please suggest it. It would be very appreciated.